# Is there a problem with PyCharm or my computer?(Mac) that doesn't let me open the simplest window?

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

When I run the following program nothing appears on my screen as you can see. The only thing I can see is the pygame icon going up and down

This is the code:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

window=(800,600)
screen=pygame.display.set_mode(window)

background = pygame.Surface(window)
background.fill((255,0,0))

loop=True
while loop:
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            loop = False
            pygame.quit()


pygame.display.update()
```

The program does nothing. I only see the python launcher icon going up and down.
Maybe it is a problem with my editor? (PyCharm) or my computer(Mac)?
I'm a beginner and I haven't ever run into this kind of problem.

Comment: The code works for me. I see a red pygame window that is 800 by 600. I am using PyCharm.

Comment: I recently updated PyCharm. Does this have to do with anything or no?

Comment: I don't think so. Try another python interpreter like IDLE or something and see if that works.

Comment: Tried with IDLE and it still doesn't work. I also tried a tkinter simple app in both PyCharm and IDLE and it works just fine. I also tried another pygame app(a simple game) which i had made a couple weeks ago and it worked perfectly. So is it a pygame problem?

Comment: I think there is a problem with pygame. Try reinstalling it.

Comment: It's probably because you're not calling `pygame.display.update()` regurarly. Try to indent it into the game loop, as QiuYU showed in their answer

Comment: I finally made it by reinstalling pygame as Qiu YU said. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))

while 1:
    screen.fill((255,0,0))
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
            
    pygame.display.update()
```

This code works on my computer. I'm using PyCharm on a mac.

Comment: Wish it worked for me:/ It's probably a python launcher problem in general

Answer (score 1):

Finally it worked for me.
I uninstalled and reinstalled pygame and now it works.